# How to bind the same key value in array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

Currently having trouble in array. I can't get my desired output.

This is my array.

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Antonio Trillanes",
  "category": "libel" 
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Liela De Lima",
  "category": "libel" 
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Gloria Macapagal Arroyo",
  "category": "plunder" 
 },
]
```

This is my desired output.

I want it in this way.

```
[
 libel: [
          {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Antonio Trillanes",
           "category": "libel" 
          },
          {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Liela De Lima",
           "category": "libel" 
          }
        ],
 plunder: [
           {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Gloria Macapagal Arroyo",
            "category": "plunder" 
           },
          ]
]
```

This is my code.

```
$convicted_persons = [];
$persons = Persons::all();
foreach($persons as $person) {
     $convicted_persons [ $person['category'] ] = $person;
}
```

I don't get my desired output using this code.

What did I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel collections:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby

`Persons::all()` is already returning a collection filled with `Person` model instances, so you can do this:

```
$persons = Persons::all();
$convicted_persons = $persons->groupBy('category');
```

Answer (score 1):

As its an object you can do like this way,

```
$temp = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $temp[$value->category][] = $value; // if not object $temp[$value['category']][] = $value;
}
print_r($temp);die;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did in a plain array:

```
$array = array(
        array(
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "Antonio Trillanes",
            "category" => "libel"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => "Liela De Lima",
            "category" => "libel"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 3,
            "name" => "Gloria Macapagal Arroyo",
            "category" => "plunder"
    ));
    $new_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $value){
        $new_array[$value['category']][] = $value;
    }
```

Just update your line as below, Just add [] after `[ $person['category'] ]`:

```
$convicted_persons [ $person['category'] ] = $person;
$convicted_persons [ $person['category'] ][] = $person;
```